# How to load external svg file with <use>? in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this!
So, here's my SVG. I have it uploaded directly to my child theme's folder and I have it renamed to "test.svg.php". I have tried naming it without the .php too, as well as with "inline" in the beginning.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    width="256px" 
height="256px" viewBox="0 0 256 256" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="extra">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M160.052,250.622c52.437-
48.419,49.47-116.202,19.158-158.051
        c-18.584-25.655-43.479-41.734-74.663-47.401c-31.064-5.645-59.962,0.82-
87.352,18.333c-1.406-20.22,4.644-36.006,19.92-47.86
        C46.139,8.639,56.551,5.53,67.934,5.532c41.745,0.004,83.492-       
0.084,125.236,0.03c28.935,0.079,50.532,21.472,51.213,50.597
        c0.231,9.845,0.051,19.7,0.051,29.549c0.001,37.757,0.057,75.518-
0.029,113.273c-0.041,18.4-7.362,33.176-22.787,43.537
        c-7.544,5.065-15.922,7.986-
25.085,8.076C184.859,250.706,173.184,250.622,160.052,250.622z"/>
<path d="M102.5,216.797c0,5.635-3.111,10.203-6.949,10.203h-
6.602C85.111,227,82,222.432,82,216.797V86.203
C82,80.568,85.111,76,88.949,76h6.602c3.838,0,6.949,4.568,6.949,10.203V216.797z
"/>
<path d="M158.464,141.167c5.635,0,10.203,3.111,10.203,6.949v6.602c0,3.838-
4.568,6.949-10.203,6.949H27.87
c-5.635,0-10.203-3.111-10.203-6.949v-6I .602c0-3.838,4.568-6.949,10.203-
6.949H158.464z"/></g>
</svg>
```

I saw people talk about loading svgs with this function:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'extra.svg' ); ?>
```

I don't understand jack shit about the function, or about php in general, so I added it like 10 different times, with slight variations in my page template, in slightly 10 different ways to try and use it correctly.

Then, I finally edit my html file to add the following:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" class="jest">
   <use xlink:href="test.svg#extra" x="10" y="10" />
</svg>
```

I also tried every possible variation of this code to try and get it to work. I've been trying to figure it out for 4 days because I'm an idiot. Please, help me not waste my time anymore and let me know how to make it work, if possible.
Thank you!

EDIT: I should say that I'm doing this because I want to load a bunch of icons several times thoughout the page and I want it to be external, because I read that's the only way to get them to cache

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox supports this, not sure any other browsers do though.

Comment: I tried it on Chrome and Safari. I also added svg4everybody (even though I may not have done it right), which theoretically makes your external svg <use> visible for all browsers. To do that, all I did is add .                              '<script src="/path/to/svg4everybody.legacy.js"></script>
<script>svg4everybody();</script>'                                                                in my External JS field, but Idk if that's even enough

Comment: Am I doing it right though? Should I have the file saved as initial-file.svg.php or file.svg.php or file.svg?

Comment: It should match the filename in the <use> xlink:href attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this [post on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) for more information on using SVGs internally vs externally.

### Internal Load

Only do this if you want to manipulate the svg image with javascript or css hover effects, etc. You should rename your svg to test.svg (without .php at the end). Format your svg file as you had it at first, with all of the paths and points.

Then in in the WordPress template file where you want the svg to show up, write:

```
include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/test.svg';
```

or, if a php block is not already open, add `<?php` first and after:

```
<?php include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/test.svg'; ?>
```

### External Load

Just use an image tag around similar code:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory() ?>/test.svg" >
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, dude! I was under the impression that internal load was referring to loading an inline svg that you have already added all the html and assigned an id for. Like by using  '<use>xlink:href="#extra"'

Comment: Based on what you told me, are both the external and internal cacheable? I tried both variations of php you gave me, but interior ones give me an error. Also,once I've added that to my editor, do I just use '<svg><use>xlink:href'?

Comment: I would forget the `<use>` thing entirely, and just use the variation of your svg that you first posted in your answer -- the one with all the coordinates.  For the one that gave you an error, did you put test.svg in a sub-directory in the child theme? If so, you need to add that before the file name, like `/subdirectory/test.svg` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for responding again man. I actually dropped the file right into my child-theme folder, along with the functions.php and all that shabang. I just got it to not give an error though, I was probably putting it at the wrong place. How do you mean to use the variation of the svg, like just load it up like an <image> ? Or, do you mean to copy the HTML of the svg right onto the page? I kinda don't want to do that because I have about 10 icons each of which would load like 4 or 5 times on the page. Some of them would also appear on other pages.

Comment: Yes, you just load it up like an image. Because, even though it's a text file with <xml>, the browser _reads_ it just like an image. By the way, the svg _so_, _so_ small, that you won't save anything worth mentioning by internal/externalizing such a tiny thing 4 or 5 times.

Comment: Cool, man, thank you!  You da man. My bad I am relatively new at this :D